# Share conditional formatting view for shared outlook calender with the whole group

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft

I have a group calendar with my colleagues in which we manage equipment. I now want to assign a color to each piece of equipment.

To do so, I've set up a new View for that folder in Outlook via View > Change View > Manage Views > Create New.

In the dialogue that follows I've selected "This folder, visible to all users" (first option).
I've then set up my conditional formatting rules. It all works nicely on my account/device. But my colleagues (all of which have owner rights) can't see the View. It just won't sync.

What can I do to make this work?
I know there has to be a way because one of my colleagues told me at his former job they had a calendar with synced conditional formatting. Unfortunately he doesn't know how they did...
I've done quite a bit of googling and honestly can't find anything that has solved this issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

PS: I'm using Outlook for Microsoft 365 on Windows 10 Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

The custom color categories you created are in your own calendar.

The minimal amount of permissions that you need to grant to make your Color Categories visible in other shared folders as well is “Can view all details” permissions (Microsoft 365 Exchange Online) or “Reviewer” permissions (Exchange on-premises).

See this link: https://www.msoutlook.info/question/color-categories-in-shared-contacts-folders

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I want to use conditional formatting (based on the title of the appointment) and not categories. This is a bit more practical, since it automatically assigns the right color for every piece of equpiment instead of the user having to remember/look up the right color and picking the category manually.